# Xcode Organizer: Valid signing identity not found

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have already one app published in App Store, but I have developed it using Adobe AIR on a Windows PC.

Now I would like to learn native programming with iOS 7, have purchased an O'Reilly book, MBA with OSX 10.8.5, Xcode 5.0 and iPhone 5c.

I guess that to try example apps on my device, I need to create a wildcard App ID and a development profile and install the latter to my iPhone.

I think this has worked well - I can see a profile at the bottom of Settings -> General -> Profiles:

[image]
But the Xcode Organizer shows a warning triangle and the warning **Valid signing identity not found**:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've searched SO and verified that my Certificates use System Defaults...

[image]

UPDATE: yes, I've added the certificate to Keychain Access:

[image]

Comment: Have you downloaded certificate and stored into keychain?

Comment: Your developer certificate is wrong

Comment: I see on this screenshot, it has no private key - compare to cert below

Comment: How to fix that? I think Xcode had created the certificate for me

Comment: I created new certificates for the user and still the profile reports back no signing identity found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, delete certificate without private key from keychain - it is useless and may generate errors in future.
Open your keychain access and generate certificate signing request (In top menu go for Keychain access -> certificate assistant -> request a certificate from signing authority). You should see this window
[image]

Select saved to disk, and enter your email address. CA email address leave blank.
Specify location of generated certificateSigningRequest file wherever you want. Then go to Apple developer member centre and create development certificate. Proceed usual procedure, select iOS app development, specify your created csr file, generate, download, add to keychain. Profit=)

Comment: I don't want to request a new development certificate, because I already have one (from my Adobe AIR app). I've finally solved my problem by importing its private key and reopening Xcode. But thanks for your help and +1 for the screenshot.

Comment: @AlexanderFarberHow to import private key? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: This helped me solve an issue with trigger.io reporting: "AMDeviceInstallApplication failed: -402620395". Problem was an unverified certificate!

Comment: 'iOS App Development' is grey out... why?

Comment: Seems like your rights don't allow you creation of dev certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I exported the .p12 file certificate from the old/original mac through KeyChain app, then import it in the new mac again with the KeyChain app, then on apple dev site edit the provisioning profile, save it, download it and re-register it in xcode

Comment: How do you edit the profile? The only option I see is to delete it.